# Specific Commit Messages for Various Files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In My Mercurial Repository, I have 4 files I modified,

When I make a Commit, The commit message applied to all Files I modified, but, there are any form to write a specific commit message for every file I modified in the commit screen??

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, every changeset should contain some specific change, be it something as small as fixing a small bug by correcting a single line in a file, or something as big as changing the signature of a function all over the codebase.

This allows you to do things like transplanting a changeset to a different branch later, which is only easy when your changesets are not polluted by unrelated stuff.

(By the way, this is the main difference between modern DVCS like Mercurial or Git, which track *changes*, and older systems like SVN, which track *revisions*.)

If you feel like you need to write separate comments for every file, this *might* mean you're actually committing *several* unrelated changes at once, which isn't good practice.

On the other hand, if it's not the case, you can of course write a multi-line message:

```
User can no longer add the same product twice (issue123)

add_product.py: added server-side validation
scripts.js: added client-side validation
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line, you can commit changes to individual files by passing them on the `hg commit` command line:

```
> hg st
M file1.cpp
M file1.h
M file2.cpp
M file2.h
> hg commit -m "Some changes" file1.cpp file1.h
> hg st
M file2.cpp
M file2.h
```

You can do the same thing using TortoiseHg by only "checking" the files you want checked in in the `thg commit` window - or more precisely, by unchecking those you don't want committed.

Note however that this will create several changesets, one for each commit. If this is not what you want, then I would agree with Helgi.

In a previous version of TortoiseHg (back when it was written using tk, so not that long ago), it was actually possible to select individual "chunks" of changes to a file and commit them separately.  However this is not available in the current version, and as far as I am aware is not planned for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the commit message applies to the changeset, which contains changes to the files you modified.

You could make multi-line messages if you want to address the changes to each file:

```
new features, fixed bugs, etc.
file1.txt: fixed bug 1234
file2.txt: refactored body of Foobar()
file3.txt: did Rot13 on the entire file, twice
file4.txt: added overload of Bar() to except a second Foo object
```

I don't recommend doing a changeset for each file, however, even though that is possible.

Comment: By the way, isn't it considered good practice to separate summary and the remaining message with an empty line?

Comment: Probably. To me it seems more of a personal preference, though one might make it part of the shop's style policy. Though we rarely have unrelated changes committed together in my shop, we're not very verbose in the commit message: they're usually one-liners.

Comment: I make the commit with the multi-line message, but, when I make a Push to the remote repository (Bitbucket), i examined the files have pushed and I saw the entire Message Commit when I revised the source file individually. I was thinking with the multi-line commit message, only the message that reference a file, was the commit message for that file. Now I have the some commit message in all files I updated, some way to change this behavior?

Comment: @Lissandro: Which is why I began by noting that the commit message is for the changeset, not the files.

Comment: Ok!! I understood!, but there are any way to make a specific file commit message, without do a commit by every related file I change?